# Decimal representation with power series

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, power-series, decimal-expansion

How can I prove the following using power series? :

> Prove that the number whose decimal expression is given by ''$e_n...e_1,\hspace{1mm}d_1...d_m\hspace{1mm}\overline{p_1...p_s}$'' where $e_j,d_i,p_k$ (for every $j=1,...,n$; $i=1,...,m$; $k=1,...,s$) represents a digit from 0 to 9, and $\overline{p_1...p_s}$ is the period, it is rational.

I'm really having trouble with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$e_n...e_1.d_1...d_m\overline{p_1...p_s} = e_n...e_1.d_1...d_m  + 0.\underbrace{0...0}_\text{m times}\overline{p_1...p_s} $ .

Then representing the second factor as $x$, subtract $10^{m+s} x $ and $x$ , What do you obtain?

To solve the problem you can finish and adapt to power series this argument.

Comment: Done. Thanks. So the proof itself would be to be able to express the number in its rational form "a/b", right?

Comment: yes , I think it suffices , you can then [accept the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :)